# How to get Registry error for file association, file/path references, program shortcut in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I am developing a registry cleaner and for that I have to find out registry error in the windows registry. If we talk about registry error in Shared dlls I get the registry error with the following code:

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\SharedDLLs");
```

same thing I want to do in case of file association, file/path references,program shortcuts. I donot know which path should I use with OpenSubKey("") to get the registry error for those in C#.

Comment: you are writing a registry cleaner, but don't know how some aspects of the registry work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "registry error"?

Comment: This is a reg cleaner i won't use definitely

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Not very surprising, given the results of mnay existing registry cleaners...

Comment: We all know that in os there are a lot of registry keys which is used to handle our applications. I m developing a application which will be used to remove the errors from the registry keys. I donot know which registry key should i use to get the errors in the registry keys of above?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have permission to access those keys - if you are running Vista or Windows 7, you will need administrator privileges to access them.

Comment: I have the admin permission but i donot know which registrykey should i use?